# Help configuring MySQL install for remote connections / root accounts understanding

Tags: mysql, security

I installed mysql/phpmyadmin/apache on a linux box for internal network use only. I don't have the strongest understanding of MySQL.

```
Hostname: server.domain.lan
IP: 192.168.0.54
```

- After I installed MySQL I ran `mysqladmin -u root password STRONGPASSWORD`
- I edited /etc/my.conf and set the bind-address to 192.168.0.54

I am trying to set up a system to run on my LAN that I can upload websites to that need to create databases.

Screenshot from phpMyAdmin of the Privileges menu:

[image: settings]

So my questions are:

- Why are there 3 root accounts?
- What do I need to do to configure MySQL to allow remote connections from the root account so I can create databases, etc?

(Sorry I'm kind of new to MySQL so I'm not certain that I'm even asking the correct questions...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**root@localhost** allows a root user to connect to mysql locally from the DB server using the mysql socket file.

**root@127.0.0.1** allows a root user to connect to mysql locally from the DB server using the TCP/IP protocol. (Trust me, you will be needing this one. MySQL has a nasty bug in it. The bug sometimes causes the mysql socket file to disappear rendering root@localhost useless. You will need to connect using root@127.0.0.1 if this ever happens to you)

**root@server.domain.lan** allows a root user to connect to mysql from server.domain.lan using DNS (Dynamic Naming Services)

**You could create root@'%' but I highly recommend you do not**.

I would also recommend using a different password for each root user.

Comment: The bug that you mentioned in your answer, is it fixed now? or does it still exist?

Comment: @its_me I finally discovered one way to recreate the problem: If you attempt to start mysqld with mysqld already running, sometimes the socket file gets deleted. I have seen other occasions when the socket file was gone without this happening. It's not a MySQL-centric issue. Sometimes, external factors in the OS may also be to blame.